# How to add a queryset column to another queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have this problem and I have searched for days and I still haven't figured out how to solve it.
I have a queryset `q1` that shows me a `model_id` and a column `available`
and I want to add that column to the `Model.objects.all()` results, but the deal is that `q1` is the result of a query to calculate the available amount so there is no table or model to refer to.
Any suggestions or any solutions?

Example Code:

```
q1=Offer.Suboffer.through.objects.values("offer_id","suboffer_id").annotate(available=F("suboffer_id__Product_offer_id__Store_Amount")/F("suboffer_id__Amount")).values("offer_id", available=Min("available"))
```

I am inside the method `get_queryset` of the `OfferListView` of my project

So the queryset that this method returns is `Offer.objects.all()`.
Before it returns I want to add that column `available` of the queryset `q1`.

```
q2=Offer.objects.all()
```

So I need a way to do a LEFT join with this 2 querysets q1 and q2 basically to set the column available in the ouput queryset q2

Update

I tried to make q1 queryset similar to q2 adding the q2 fields by hand to q1

```
q2=q1.values(available,Price=(F"offer_id__Price"),id=F("offer_id"))
```

(* I summarize the values but in fact I manually inserted 6 values to make it compatible with the q2 queryset)

And returning q2 this way achieving what I wanted... but still want to know a correct way to do it because it seems very tedious and in cases of tables of large amount of columns it should be impossible

Last Update
I think I got it. Add OuterRef and Subquery and modify q1 to convert it to a subquery

```py
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
q1=q1.filter(offer_id=OuterRef("pk"))
q2=Offer.objects.annotate(available=Subquery(q.values("available")))
```

Comment: Please add some example code.

Comment: @Glenn DJ tell me if you need anything else  I am not sure if it was enough code so please tell me  and I will add the models or something else ✌thxs for commenting